# Handle external API calls inside an api

Tags: api-design

I have a simple HTTP server where you can create and manage todos. You can also add plugins in order to, for example, send an email to the people who starred a todo when that todo has been completed. I currently check for all enabled plugins through an query to the database, and then query each API endpoint for the different plugins (Gmail, Notion, Trello, etc). After this is finished, I send a response back to the user. This is a problem, because it means I rely on the speed of the external API's I am requesting for my response. If the Notion api is slow, then my endpoint is also slow.

Is there a way to first send a response after, for example, the server marks the todo as completed, but then send a different response after all the plugins have been queried (Gmail, Notion, Trello, etc)? Would I have to use web sockets? Or is the way I currently handle external API queries the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right thinking that you want to decouple requests from customers with backend processing (reaching out other providers); and web sockets is one of options to do that. HTTP2 streams is another options. And, of course, pulling is also a way (simple, but not too efficient).

Comment: Can HTTP2 streams or web sockets handle as many requests as a normal HTTP request? If not, should it be something I should think/worry about when creating the system or is it still able to scale relatively easily?

Comment: yes, the idea behind streams (and websockets) is to reduce the overhead of continuous communication. For example, no need to reestablish TLS for every request/response.